# run cmd with clink as administrator in windows to save your command history permanently

Tags: windows, cmd, administrator

I downloaded clink because I wanted a windows cmd interface that saved the history of the commands I was introducing. The problem is that clink always run in a non admin user, even if you execute the Batch file Clink v0.4.9 as admin.
So I want to know how to make Clink run as it is
intentionally executed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Batch file Clink v0.4.9, the last lines are written as

```
:launch
start "Clink" cmd.exe /s /k ""%~dpnx0" inject %clink_profile_arg%"
exit /b 0
```

So you just need to change them for these

```
:launch
start "Clink" cmd.exe /s /k pushd ""%V"" ""%~dpnx0" inject %clink_profile_arg%"
exit /b 0
```

If you want to check whether you are in admin mode, use

```
net session
```

as indicated in the following stackoverflow post

[How to detect if CMD is running as Administrator/has elevated privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985755/how-to-detect-if-cmd-is-running-as-administrator-has-elevated-privileges/7987153)

Now you have a windows cmd which saves your command history permanently in user and admin modes.

[image]